# Is it possible to embed a .Net code in SSRS to remove CSV header from CSV file instead of changing report server configuration?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Is it possible to embed a .Net code in SSRS to remove CSV header from CSV file instead of changing report server configuration? As client is not ready to change rsreportconfiguration setting.

Comment: Did my answer help you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to view a report from the report server and then export it as a CSV? These export functions are handled by the server and do not check or run any code from your .rdl file. So no, this is not possible.

One possible workaround might have been to rename the textboxes with the first row of data. But this doesn't work with numbers or blanks and it's not dynamic.

A better solution will probably end up being to ignore the headers wherever these are being consumed. If that's not possible, SSRS might not be the best tool for this job. Then you might look at generating the CSV with SSIS or some other ETL process.